# How to get window handle (int) from chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, window-handles

I got a chrome extension and in the event of a new tab I want to get the window handle in windows if the current window.

On the event I got the tab object and I got chrome's internal window id but this is not the handle in windows.

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(
        function (tab)
        {
            var intMainWindowHwnd = 0; // how to get it? not tab.windowId…
        });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if anyone encounter the same problem, i solved it using a [NPAPI](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html) Plugin in C++ that get access to win32api...

In Invoke method i've checked for my method (GetProcessId) and got the parent process (since the addon is in a different process):

```
ULONG_PTR MyAddon::GetParentProcessId() // By Napalm @ NetCore2K
{
 ULONG_PTR pbi[6];
 ULONG ulSize = 0;
 LONG (WINAPI *NtQueryInformationProcess)(HANDLE ProcessHandle, ULONG ProcessInformationClass,
  PVOID ProcessInformation, ULONG ProcessInformationLength, PULONG ReturnLength); 
 *(FARPROC *)&NtQueryInformationProcess = 
  GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("NTDLL.DLL"), "NtQueryInformationProcess");
 if(NtQueryInformationProcess){
  if(NtQueryInformationProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), 0,
    &pbi, sizeof(pbi), &ulSize) >= 0 && ulSize == sizeof(pbi))
     return pbi[5];
 }
 return (ULONG_PTR)-1;
}
```

Then i got the main hwnd of this process and return it to my js addon.

Comment: Could you expand a little but on your answer, such as including sample code? The current answer is barely useful.